# Why do my Radio buttons state not updating?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I've tried :

- using two Obx, one for each RadioListTile
- use TextEditingController() as the variable and get the value from gender.text

But the RadioButtons still selecting the initial value/

Minimal code reproduction:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Controller extends GetxController {
  var gender = "F".obs;

  void onChangedGender(String? value) {
    gender = (value ?? "M").obs;
    print(gender.value);
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Obx(
            () => Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: "M",
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Male"),
                    onChanged: c.onChangedGender,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: "F",
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Female"),
                    onChanged: c.onChangedGender,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try online: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zla606cyla70?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

Comment: Inside your onChangedGender()  change the line ( gender = (value ?? "M").obs; )  into ->    gender.value = value ?? "M";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void onChangedGender(String? value) {
    gender.value = (value ?? "M");
  }
```

replace your function with the above

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Controller extends GetxController {
  RxInt gender = 1.obs;

  void onChangedGender(Object? v) {
    gender.value = int.parse(v.toString());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Obx(
            () => Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Male"),
                    onChanged: (v){
                      c.onChangedGender(v);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Female"),
                    onChanged: (v){
                      c.onChangedGender(v);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I don't understand why. Does Radio not support string as value or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Turns out the problem was because I reassigned the gender in onChangedGender. I should've only set the value. Using RxString works, it doesn't have to be RxInt.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you want the state of widget to change you should be using stateful widget and not stateless widget.
2. To change the state of the widget in stateful widget you should use function setState.

Your modified working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Controller extends GetxController {
  var gender = "F".obs;

  void onChangedGender(String? value) {
    gender = (value ?? "M").obs;
    print(gender.value);
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Obx(
            () => Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: "M",
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Male"),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() { c.onChangedGender(val); }); 
                      },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    value: "F",
                    groupValue: c.gender.value,
                    title: const Text("Female"),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() { c.onChangedGender(val); }); 
                      },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatelessWidget  {
    @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MyWidget();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I avoid using StatefulWidget because I'm already using GetX as my state manager.